# How to update a PostgreSQL table with a list in Python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices (
    ticker VARCHAR(32),
    time TIMESTAMP,
    open FLOAT8,
    high FLOAT8,
    low FLOAT8,
    close FLOAT8,
    volume FLOAT8,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticker, time)
) PARTITION BY LIST (ticker);
```

and want to update it via SQLAlchemy in a Python server.
I get my data from an API in an array with the columns timestamp in miliseconds, opening price, highest price, lowest price, closing price and volume.
Example for Apple (ticker = AAPL):

```
timestamp, opening price, highest price, lowest price, closing price, volume
[[1264982400000,6.870357036590576,7,6.8321428298950195,6.9546427726745605,749876400],
[1265068800000,6.996786117553711,7.0114288330078125,6.906428813934326,6.994999885559082,698342400],
[1265155200000,6.9703569412231445,7.150000095367432,6.943571090698242,7.115356922149658,615328000],
...]
```

What is the best way to update the columns of the table stock_prices WHERE ticker = 'AAPL' with the entrees of the array?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question!

Comment: I used to have a table for each stock, but now i work with more stocks and such the amount of tables was getting quite high. When i had a table for each stock i used the to_sql() function from pandas, but I don't know how to achieve a similar result, when using a partitioned table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this question, here is how i solved it:

```
            df = pd.DataFrame(tOHLCV, columns=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])

            df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] * 1_000_000)

            df.set_index('time')

            df.to_sql(f'{ticker}_tmp', db.engine, if_exists='replace')

            sql += f'''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {ticker}_partition
                PARTITION OF stock_prices
                FOR VALUES IN ('{ticker}');

                INSERT INTO stock_prices (
                    ticker,
                    time,
                    open,
                    high,
                    low,
                    close,
                    volume
                )
                SELECT
                    '{ticker}',
                    time,
                    open,
                    high,
                    low,
                    close,
                    volume
                FROM public."{ticker}_tmp"
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
                ;                
            '''

            sql += f'''
                DROP TABLE public."{ticker}_tmp";
            '''

            db.session.execute(sql, values)
            db.session.commit()
```